# Почему в js не работает задержка?

Tags: javascript

```js
 document.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    if(event.target.classList.contains('block')) {
      event.target.classList.add('block-active')
    }
  
 });
 
 document.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
  
    if(event.target.classList.contains('block')) {
      event.target.classList.remove('block-active').delay(1000)
    }
  
 });
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
}
.block-active {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="block">
        
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что у результата функции `remove` есть метод `delay`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`remove().delay()` есть в jQuery, но в чистом js у `remove()` нет такого метода.

Ты должен использовать `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(() => event.target.classList.remove('block-active'), 1000)
```